# User confirmation, login with username and email

Tags: laravel, authentication, message

I changed the login function a bit, that the user can only log in with his username and his email if his email address was confirmed by a sent email.

what do I want to do

1. If the email address has not yet been confirmed, I would like to redirect the user to a page to confirm his email address. If the table "users, active" has a 1, the address has been confirmed.
2. Currently I have problems logging in with the username. Does anyone recognize a mistake?

How can I implement that? Does anyone have a similar code?

```
/**
    * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return array
    */
   protected function credentials(Request $request)
   {
       $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
           ? $this->username()
           : 'username';

       return [
           $field => $request->get($this->username()),
           'password' => $request->password,
       ];
   }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => [
                'required', 'string',
                Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query){
                    $query->where('active', true);
                })
            ],
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ], $this->validationError());
    }
```

New loginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/iboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'userLogout']]);
    }

    /**
    * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return array
    */
   protected function credentials(Request $request)
   {

       $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
           ? $this->username()
           : 'username';

       return [
           $field => $request->get($this->username()),
           'password' => $request->password,

       ];

   }
```

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

```
    if (Auth::once($this->credentials($request))) {  //use auth once so that it will not create auth session
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->active){
            Auth::login($user); //now create auth session, check
            return redirect('/iboard'); //redirect to dashboard url
        }else{
            return redirect('email_confirm')->with('fail', 'Please confirm your email'); //redirect to email confirm page
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('fail', "Invalid username or password");
}

    public function userLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('')->logout();
        return view('/exit');
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query){
                    $query->where('active', true);
                })` from validation, because then it doesn't allow inactive user to login. once user login then check user has active 1 like this if ($user->active != 1 ) logout user and then redirect to confirm email page

Comment: do you have a code example or similar?

Comment: can you post your login action code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code for your login, assuming you have `validateLogin` and `credentials` functions in the same controller because the below login action used both of these function. Check details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if (Auth::once($this->credentials($request))) {  //use auth once so that it will not create auth session
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->active == 1){
            Auth::login($user); //now create auth session
            return redirect('dashboard'); //redirect to dashboard url
        }else{
            return redirect('email_confirm')->with('error', 'Please confirm your email'); //redirect to email confirm page
        }
    }

     return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Invalid username or password"); 
}
```

Comment: I use the auth system from laravel. When I use your code, I always get the same error message: Invalid username or password. If the data is correct, it log me in. I have added my current logincontroller to my question.

Comment: my mistake,  forget to add return before `redirect`, updated answer check it

Comment: I can log in, although the user is not active

Comment: what do you store in `active` field ? try `if($user->active == 1)` updated answer

Comment: if the user active is a 1 saved, it is locked a 2 and if it was not activated, a 0. I have adapted the code but it logs in anyway.

Comment: did you add `if($user->active == 1)` condition check ?

Comment: yes I tried, but I can log in although the user has a 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176133/discussion-between-rkj-and-slickness).